# Unable To Find Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, stripe-connect

I've been having an issue all day and cannot figure it out. I'm new to iOS developing, so any guidance or answers would be beyond appreciated!

I'm trying to install Stripe via Cocoapods. I keep getting the error in my terminal that it's unable to find the project.

Here is my Pod file:

[image: Pod file]

Here is the location with all the files:

[image: location with all the files]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your pod file `project` path should be:

```
~/Downloads/...
```

***Not***

```
~Downloads/...
```

`~/` is relative to your users home directory, however, `~` without the `/` is not.

Comment: FYI - `~Downloads/...` would be looking for the home directory of a user named `Downloads`.